# Best documentclass for formulary (cheat sheet)

Tags: document-classes

We are allowed to bring a formulary of 2 pages to our math exam. Obviously I need to put as much content on it as possible, using the tiniest font size available.
Unfortunately I haven't found a documentclass that suits my needs.
Currently I'm using this one:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn,notitlepage]{article}
```

It has large margins, i.e. empty areas. Also, the font size is pretty large.

Is there any predefined documentclass for my purpose?

Comment: Basically none of the options to `article` in your example is suited to obtain the requested result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses a very small font size and small margin values by applying options to the geometry package.

`\fontsize{6}{8}\selectfont` is just one way to use (even smaller would be hardly readable, so it's not recommended)

`multicols` allows for organzing in multiple columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, lmargin=0.2cm,rmargin=0.2cm,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\fontsize{6pt}{8pt}\selectfont

\begin{multicols}{8}
\foreach \x in {1,...,800} {

\(
E=mc^2
\)

}
\end{multicols}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please no comment on `E=mc^2` ... I am a physicist and know that yonder formula is not really used in Mathematics at all ;-)